# How To Fetch Multiple Uploaded Images By Current User - Firebase and Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I wanted to know what is the best way to fetch images which are uploaded by the user on my app. Currently, the images are all being saved in storage. I assume this is not the correct way as it has nothing to do with userId? Perhaps, I need to save user media in real time database in order to fetch their images? If someone could help me, that will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

```
 guard let image = imageView.image, let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
        else {

            print("something went wrong")
            return
    
        }
        
        let imageName = UUID().uuidString
        let imageReference = Storage.storage().reference().child(MyKeys.imagesFolder).child(imageName)
        
        imageReference.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, err) in
            
            
            if let err = err {
                print ("Error")
                return
            }
            
            imageReference.downloadURL(completion: { (url, err) in
                    
                if let err = err {
                    print ("Error")
                    return
                }
                
                guard let url = url else {
                    print ("Error")
                    return
                }
                
                let dataReference = Firestore.firestore().collection(MyKeys.imagesCollection).document()
                
                let documentUid = dataReference.documentID
                                                
                let urlString = url.absoluteString
                
                let data = [
                    MyKeys.uid:documentUid,
                    MyKeys.imageUrl: urlString,
                    MyKeys.imageTitle: self.imageTitle.text!,

                ] as [String : Any]
                
                dataReference.setData(data) { (err) in
                    if let err = err {
                        print ("Error")
                        return
                    }
             
                }
                
            })
            
            }
    }
```

Comment: Probably wouldn't want to store images in the Realtime Database. What you probably *do* want to do is store your images in Firebase Storage and make sure that they have the user ID (`Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid`) in the image reference path (for example: `\(uid)/\(filename)`)

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks! I've now saved images as Userid.Imagetitle - it does make it much easier. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty common pattern is to store the user ID in the image's path in Firebase Storage. For example,

```
let imageName = //...
guard let uidString = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
  return
}
let imageRefPath = "\(uidString)/\(imageName)"
```

Comment: Super answer! I would like to add that once the image url is constructed and image saved in Storage, that url (which is a reference the image) would then be stored in the Realtime Database or Firestore. The OP appears to be doing that but just wanted to add that note for completeness.

Comment: Yes! This helped me a lot and since then I have been able to store it and it is much more easier! Thank you so much :)